# SpringData MongoRepository Count and Where clause combination

Tags: spring-data, mongorepository

I m using MongoDb and SpringData MongoRepository.. I want to fetch count messages where receiver user = ? and message readed = ? ... 
 In short I want to fetch users unreaded messages.My method like this..But I haven't any idea how do this..Message is my mongo document.. Thanks.

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends MongoRepository<Message, Long> {

    Long countByReadedWhereReceiverIs(boolean readed,String receiver);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

```
int countFindByReadedAndReceiver(boolean readed, String receiver);
```